# How to generate JavaScript output from the latest Canvg version(4.0.1)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, canvg

We are using the Canvg plugin version(2.0.0) (https://github.com/canvg/canvg) in our Javascript project. We are trying to upgrade it to the latest version (4.0.1). We don't use any package manager like npm in our project. We are directly using the script reference in our HTML files.

The older Canvg plugin is in Javascript and the latest version is in Typescript.

As we are referencing the JavaScript file in our Html, we need a solution to make use of the latest Canvg version in the form of Javascript. Please share your comments on this.